# Fetch data from postgresql table missing in another table using Sequelize

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I tried retrieving data from a Postgres SQL table missing in another table but received `SequelizeLoadingError`.

I am trying to retrieve a list of books that has not been rented by a particular user.

**Book Controller**

```
  getBooks(req, res) {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    return Book
      .findAll({
        where: Sequelize.literal('RentedBook.userId IS  null'),
        include: [
          { model: RentedBook }
    ]
  })
   .then((books) => {
    if (books.length < 1) {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: 'There is no book in the database'
          });
        } else {
          res.status(201).send(books);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(404).send(error));
  },
```

**Book Model**

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Books = sequelize.define('Book', {
   title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: DataTypes.FALSE,
    },
    isbn: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      required: true,
    },
    total: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      required: true
    },
    prodYear: DataTypes.STRING,
    catId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    cover: DataTypes.STRING,
    author: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations can be defined here
         Books.hasMany(models.RentedBook, {
      foreignKey: 'bookId'
        });
        Books.hasOne(models.Category, {
          foreignKey: 'catId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
   }
  });
  return Books;
};
```

**Rented Book Model**

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const RentedBook = sequelize.define('RentedBook', {
    bookId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    toReturnDate: DataTypes.DATE,
    returnDate: DataTypes.DATE,
    returned: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
    // associations can be defined here
        RentedBook.BelongsTo(models.Book, {
          foreignKey: 'bookId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
        RentedBook.BelongsTo(models.User, {
          foreignKey: 'userId',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return RentedBook;
};
```

I will appreciate any help for me to fetch books that exist in the book table but has not been rented before by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by querying the book database, fetching the list of rented books where Username is not the same as the currently logged in username.